# How can I make this loop increase by 1.8 each iteration?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
print("Year\tRise (in mm)")
print("------------------")

for number in range(1, 26):
    rise = number + 1.8
    print(number, '\t', rise)
```

So basically, rise is supposed to increase by 1.8 each time.

1 = 1.8
2 = 3.6
so on

Answer (score 1):

Make `rise` adding instead of `number`:

```
rise = 0
for number in range(1, 26):
    rise += 1.8
    print(number, '\t', rise)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know syntax for Python, but it should be a multiplication to get what you want, instead of addition, so it should be:
rise = number * 1.8

Answer (score 0):

```
rise = 0.0

print("Year\tRise (in mm)")
print("------------------")

for number in range(1, 26):
    rise += 1.8
    print(number, '\t', format(rise, '.2f'))
```

i figured it out

Comment: Sorry, this is exactly my answer, so don't forget to accept if it works.